# VirtualizingPanel stops ScrollViewer working within Viewbox

Tags: wpf, panel, virtualization, scrollviewer, viewbox

I have a simple custom panel that is hosted within the `ItemsPanel` of an `ItemsControl`. The `Template` of the `ItemsControl` is updated to surround the `ItemsPresenter` with a `Viewbox` and a `ScrollViewer`. Here is the XAML code:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
    AncestorType={x:Type Local:MainWindow}}}" 
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True">
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ItemsControl}">
            <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
                <Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </Viewbox>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Local:TestPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Height="250" Width="250" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                Content="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

And the `Panel`:

```
public class TestPanel : Panel
{
    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        var desiredSize = new Size();
        var layoutSlotSize = availableSize;

        layoutSlotSize.Height = double.PositiveInfinity;
        for (int i = 0, count = InternalChildren.Count; i < count; ++i)
        {
            UIElement child = InternalChildren[i];
            if (child == null) continue;
            child.Measure(layoutSlotSize);
            var childDesiredSize = child.DesiredSize;
            desiredSize.Width = Math.Max(desiredSize.Width, childDesiredSize.Width);
            desiredSize.Height += childDesiredSize.Height;
        }
        return desiredSize;
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        double verticalOffset = 0;
        for (int i = 0, count = InternalChildren.Count; i < count; ++i)
        {
            UIElement child = InternalChildren[i];
            if (child == null) continue;
            child.Arrange(new Rect(0, verticalOffset, child.DesiredSize.Width, 
                child.DesiredSize.Height));
            verticalOffset += child.DesiredSize.Height;
        }
        return base.ArrangeOverride(finalSize);
    }
}
```

And finally, `MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Buttons = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        IEnumerable<int> characterCodes = Enumerable.Range(65, 26);
        foreach (int characterCode in characterCodes) 
            Buttons.Add(((char)characterCode).ToString().ToUpper());
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonsProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Buttons), typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), 
        typeof(MainWindow), null);

    public ObservableCollection<string> Buttons
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ButtonsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonsProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

This all works as expected... so far, so good. The problem is when I change the base class from `Panel` to `VirtualizingPanel`, which I need to do to virtualise the data (not this example button data). After changing the base class, the panel immediately stops working. I am totally aware of how to virtualize data in a panel... I have a working example of this. My problem is when I want to put add a `Viewbox` inside the `ScrollViewer`.

Please note that this XAML will work fine with a normal `Panel`, or `StackPanel`, but as soon as I change it to `VirtualizingPanel`, it stops working (nothing is rendered, and the `InternalChildren` property contains no elements). Can anyone shed some light on this problem for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still do not know why the `VirtualizingPanel` does not work within a `ViewBox` within a `ScrollViewer`, but I have discovered that if I extend the `VirtualizingStackPanel` class in my panel instead, everything works as expected.

Therefore, the solution for those who require virtualized items to be stacked is to extend the `VirtualizingStackPanel` class instead. For those who need other types of child arrangement, I'm sorry, but I have no answer, unless you remove the `Viewbox`.

I would still be more than happy to receive any further information on this subject.